# Test-Kitchen Cannot Converge Centos Machine using kitchen-vra

Tags: chef-infra, centos7, test-kitchen

I'm trying to converge a test-kitchen image, using Centos catalog item, in vra, below are my results.

I'm able to kitchen create, but converge gives the errors I am showing in the log section below.

**kitchen yaml file**

```
---
  driver:
    name: vra
    username: <%= ENV['VRA_USER'] %>
    password: "<%= ENV['VRA_PASS'] %>"
    tenant: Engineering
    base_url: [base_url]
    verify_ssl: false
    cpus: 2
    memory: 8192
    lease_days: 7
    request_timeout: 1200
    use_dns: false
    server_ready_retries: 10
  
  provisioner:
    name: chef_zero
    require_chef_omnibus: true
    retry_on_exit_code:
      - 35
    max_retries: 10
    wait_for_retry: 120
    client_rb:
      exit_status: :enabled
      client_fork: false  
    install_strategy: once
  
  verifier:
    name: pester
    test_folder: ./test/integration/
  
  platforms:
    # Describes a Windows host, remove if unneeded
    - name: Windows
      driver:
        catalog_name: [catalog_name]
        subtenant_id: [subtenant_id]
        extra_parameters:
          provider-VirtualMachine.Disk1.Size:
            type: string
            value: 60
          provider-VirtualMachine.Disk1.Label:
            type: string
            value: DATA
          provider-VirtualMachine.Disk1.Letter:
            type: string
            value: D
      transport:
        name: winrm
        username: <%= ENV['VRA_USER'] %>
        password: "<%= ENV['VRA_PASS'] %>"
    - name: Linux
      driver:
        private_key_path: ./id_rsa
        catalog_id: [catalog_id]
        subtenant_id: [subtenant_id]
      transport:
        username: [username]

  suites:
    - name: Test
      attributes:
```

**log**

```
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:33.623891 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: -----> Converging <Test-Linux>...
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:33.626019 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: Preparing files for transfer
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:33.626210 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: Installing cookbooks for Policyfile /home/engineering/chef-repo/cookbooks/learn_chef/Policyfile.rb using `chef install`
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:34.905228 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: Installing cookbooks from lock
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:34.906863 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: Installing learn_chef 0.1.0
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:34.926572 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: Preparing dna.json
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:34.927109 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: Exporting cookbook dependencies from Policyfile /tmp/Test-Linux-sandbox-20200812-8500-duuh91...
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:36.924522 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: Exported policy 'learn_chef' to /tmp/Test-Linux-sandbox-20200812-8500-duuh91
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:36.924628 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: 
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:36.924665 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: To converge this system with the exported policy, run:
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:36.924707 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux:   cd /tmp/Test-Linux-sandbox-20200812-8500-duuh91
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:36.924732 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux:   chef-client -z
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:36.942327 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: Removing non-cookbook files before transfer
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:36.942821 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: Preparing validation.pem
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:36.943355 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: Preparing client.rb
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:37.024902 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: [SSH] connection failed, retrying in 1 seconds (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user engineering@10.12.227.33>)
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:38.107041 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: [SSH] connection failed, retrying in 1 seconds (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user engineering@10.12.227.33>)
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:39.182940 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: [SSH] connection failed, retrying in 1 seconds (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user engineering@10.12.227.33>)
I, [2020-08-12T16:18:40.265909 #8500]  INFO -- Test-Linux: [SSH] connection failed, retrying in 1 seconds (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user engineering@10.12.227.33>)
W, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.344216 #8500]  WARN -- Test-Linux: [SSH] connection failed, terminating (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user engineering@10.12.227.33>)
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346006 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: Converge failed on instance <Test-Linux>.
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346159 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: ------Exception-------
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346196 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346211 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: Message: SSH session could not be established
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346276 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: ----------------------
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346391 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: ------Backtrace-------
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346416 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/provisioner/base.rb:95:in `rescue in call'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346432 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/provisioner/base.rb:94:in `call'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346454 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:409:in `block in converge_action'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346466 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:552:in `synchronize_or_call'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346477 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:514:in `block in action'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346489 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346509 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:513:in `action'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346527 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:404:in `converge_action'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346539 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:382:in `block (2 levels) in transition_to'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346550 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/lifecycle_hooks.rb:45:in `run_with_hooks'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346561 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:381:in `block in transition_to'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346574 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:380:in `each'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346586 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:380:in `transition_to'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346598 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:140:in `converge'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346609 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:198:in `public_send'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346622 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:198:in `run_action_in_thread'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346634 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in run_action'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346646 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/logging-2.2.2/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:474:in `block in create_with_logging_context'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346663 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: ----End Backtrace-----
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346675 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: ---Nested Exception---
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346686 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: Class: Kitchen::Transport::SshFailed
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346697 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: Message: SSH session could not be established
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346708 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: ----------------------
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346718 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: ------Backtrace-------
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346729 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/provisioner/base.rb:95:in `rescue in call'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346743 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/provisioner/base.rb:94:in `call'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346755 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:409:in `block in converge_action'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346766 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:552:in `synchronize_or_call'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346777 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:514:in `block in action'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346791 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346805 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:513:in `action'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346816 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:404:in `converge_action'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346833 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:382:in `block (2 levels) in transition_to'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346845 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/lifecycle_hooks.rb:45:in `run_with_hooks'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346860 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:381:in `block in transition_to'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346871 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:380:in `each'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346882 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:380:in `transition_to'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346892 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/instance.rb:140:in `converge'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346907 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:198:in `public_send'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346922 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:198:in `run_action_in_thread'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346933 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/test-kitchen-2.4.0/lib/kitchen/command.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in run_action'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.346945 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/logging-2.2.2/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:474:in `block in create_with_logging_context'
E, [2020-08-12T16:18:41.347029 #8500] ERROR -- Test-Linux: ----End Backtrace-----
```

I've insured that I have all the gems I need but maybe there is an issue with my config, idk...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The only thing I can think of, looking at the SSH error is the `private_key: ./id_rsa`. You could check if it is accessible, or the permissions of this key (`chmod 0600`) are correct. Another option is to try adding this key to `ssh-agent`.

Comment: I'm not super strong with linux, so I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You haven't mentioned where your SSH private key `id_rsa` is located. But you can add your private key to SSH agent with `ssh-add ./id_rsa`. If agent is not running, then start with `eval $(ssh-agent)`. Or change permissions with `chmod 0600 ./id_rsa`